# What is the real meaning of an integrated graphics processor?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, intel-graphics

I was looking up the specifications of a central processing unit I needed to buy for an upgrade and then I noticed that in the product description of the processor they had indicated Intel HD Graphics 500. This raises the question of how can an onboard iGPU be switchable unless the graphics processor is inbuilt into the CPU itself.

So my questions are:

- Does changing a processor change the iGPU if its CPU inbuilt?
- How do you know if your onboard graphics processor is on the motherboard or inside the CPU?

I also noticed several websites associating certain processors with the onboard graphics processor, for example an i7-3770 uses an Intel HD graphics 4000 and an i5-3570 uses an Intel HD Graphics 2500. So if a user decides to remove the i5 and replace it with the i7 will the graphics change too?

Comment: **An Intel GPU will never exist on a motherboard.** Intel doesn’t produce or manufacture motherboards.  So if you have an Intel GPU in your support it will always be part of the processor.  Of course Intel only recently  came out with a dGPU but only system designers can purchase it. As for Intel HD Graphics 2500 and Intel HD Graphics 4000 they are the same generation but different generation tiers.

Comment: Your title is one question, and there are two other questions in the body of your question. Please edit your post to focus on a single question. Certain CPUs have a built-in GPU. These are called "integrated", and changing the CPU changes the integrated GPU BECAUSE THEY ARE THE SAME PHYSICAL THING.

Comment: Technically, an Intel GPU will most definitely exist on the motherboard. That was how things were before iGPUs. Plenty of chipsets with integrated graphics exist. iGPUs, of course, are always in the CPU, as the name indicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was looking up the specifications of a central processing unit i needed to buy for an upgrade and then I noticed that in the product description of the processor, they had indicated intel hd graphics 500,which raises the question, how can an onboard iGPU be switchable unless the graphics processor is inbuilt into the cpu itself.

You cannot; An Intel iGPU will always be part of the processor so it’s impossible to change your Intel GPU without changing the processor in your system.

> So my questions are: Does changing a processor change the iGPU if its cpu inbuilt and then how do you know if your onboard graphics processor is on the motherboard or inside the cpu?

The only way to upgrade an Intel iGPU is to upgrade the processor.

> I also noticed several websites associating certain processors with the onboard gaphics processor, for example an i7-3770 uses an intel hd graphics 4000 and an i5-3570 uses an intel hd graphics 2500.

As for Intel HD Graphics 2500 and Intel HD Graphics 4000 they are the same generation but different generation tiers.  Both of those Intel iGPUs were from the third generation but had a slightly different amount of shaders.  This is essential what Nvidia has done with their GeForce 30 series cards by releasing the GeForce RTX 3080 in 2020 and the GeForce RTX 3080 Ti in 2021

Comment: They were released about the same time

Comment: @CodeTiger - Intel is set to release a dedicated GPU to the market themselves but it will only be sold with a device that contains an Intel processor. You won’t be able to purchase it (by itself) from the same web store as a GeForce RTX 3080.  Your question has nothing to do about the performance of these iGPUs

Comment: I will just remove that part of my answer, it has nothing, to do with your question.

Comment: [Intel Iris Xe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Xe) I will answer no questions about this product.

Comment: Okay but my point was if intel is that good with processors, think of how good they can be with dedicated gpus? Thats my point

Comment: @CodeTiger - They have not actually released it.  However, the specifications on paper are worse than current generation products from AMD and Nvidia. Intel’s have held their own but are almost always worse than a comparable product from AMD or Nvidia